# Making an existing systemd service wait for oneshot

Tags: debian, systemd, systemctl

I have a oneshot service I want to finish running (not just start), before the networking.service starts running.
I read up on the manpages and thought that this would be enough

```
[Unit]
Description=mypre networking service
Before=networking.service
Requires=networking.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/configuremodem.bash
TimeoutStartSec=1min

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target network-online.target
```

This service takes around 20seconds, and when I log into the system and check on the status, it's still running.
After checking the critical-path with systemd-analyze, I can see that this service was started before networking.service, but systemd did not wait for it to finish. I thought that, that was the whole point of oneshots from reading the manpages.
I also just achieved the result I wanted by changing:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/configuremodem.bash
ExecStart=/bin/echo done
```

After I read that ExecStart doesn't get executed until the Pre exits.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!